# Can you change the RemoteApp location of a published app?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

We would like to be able to roll out new versions of an application in RemoteApp without having to kick off users. One idea was to publish the new version of the application in a different directory, say APP/VERSION_XXX, and then update the location. There doesn't appear to be a way change the location via the management tools, but is there a way to do so via powershell?